# Where did Elm's (<~) function go? No longer in Signal module

Tags: elm

I'm looking through the http://elm-by-example.org tutorials.  `import Signals exposing ((<~))` no longer works in elm-lang/core 3.0.0, and I see in the [Elm package documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Signal) that this function has been dropped from the Signals module. Where did it go?

Here's the full type signature:

```
(<~) : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(<~)` was dropped from Elm 0.16 according to [changelog](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.16.md#updating-library-usages), because Elm generally discourages infix operators. See also [original proposal](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elm-discuss/gOU1yxAgWA8/raqfieuLCQAJ) to deprecate `(<~)` and `(~)`.

You can still find [`(<~)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/Signal-Extra#%3C~) and [`(~)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/Signal-Extra#~) in Apanatshka's [`elm-signal-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/) library.